How to Calculate Total Power in an Unbalanced Star-Delta System?
Q: I have a 230 V/50 Hz three-phase system with both star and delta loads connected to the same supply. The system is unbalanced, and I can only measure the line currents (I1, I2 & I3) and line-neutral voltages using an energy meter. The neutral current isn't measured directly.
My main goal is to calculate the total power consumed by the entire system, which includes both the star and delta loads.
What is the correct method to approach this calculation with the given data?
We have a 3-phase energy meter tried to use that one. But we can only measure line currents (L1, L2 & L3), line-neutral voltage for each phase, apparent power and reactive power. In energy meter we are using ATM90E32AS-AU-R IC.

example wiring diagram.

Does your Energymeter use phases? Does it need "passages" of one "reference" voltage across 0 V?

Are you measuring the currents and voltages in real time and recording the waveforms?

We designed an energy meter for 3-phase 3-wire or 4-wire systems. In our setup, star and delta loads are mixed on the same 3-phase source.
Given this mixed system:
Will the energy meter accurately measure the total power consumed by both star and delta loads combined?
Are there any considerations or corrections required to ensure accurate measurement under these conditions?
Thank you for taking the time to address my concern. I greatly appreciate your guidance!


The system is unbalanced, and I can only measure the line currents
(I1, I2&I3) and line-Neutral voltages using an energy meter.

If you don't know what the power factors of the loads are you can't calculate power.

My main goal is to calculate the total power consumed by the entire
system, which includes both the star and delta loads.

If you don't know what the power factors of the loads are you can't calculate power.

What is the correct method to approach this calculation with the given
data?

There isn't a viable method because you don't know the load power factors.
Of course if your energy meter gave you energy values (I guess it should) then that will relate to true power consumed so, what you could do is use a timer and calculate the energy increase over that time period. Then divide by the number of seconds to get total power. However, this might be a bit hit-and-miss because you might have to wait several minutes to get a decent resolution on the accumulated energy taken by the loads.

Thank you for the suggestion! My issue is more specific: our energy meter measures 3-phase 3-wire (delta) or 3-phase 4-wire (star) systems, but our setup has a mix of star and delta loads on the same supply. The meter reads only total line currents and voltages but doesn't account for neutral current from the star load. My concern is whether the meter accurately calculates total power consumption in this mixed system. Could the configuration or unmeasured neutral current cause inaccuracies?

@octane it will be accurate -- look up Blondel's theorem.

Thank you for addressing my concerns and mentioning Blondel's Theorem. I truly appreciate your effort. While I’ve reviewed the theorem and understand its relevance to accurate power measurement in polyphase systems, I noticed it does not explicitly discuss mixed star and delta loads on the same 3-phase supply.
I am curious whether the theorem applies in this specific case. As a beginner, I would also like to ask if there’s a practical way to verify the meter’s output for accuracy. Thank you again for your guidance!
